# Print all buttons in order of their click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 10 buttons 0-9. I want to print out all the numbers of the buttons in order of their 'click'. For example, If I click on buttons 5,4,3,2,1 then it should be printed like 54321 but with my coding it is printing in ascending order only. Can anybody help me figure this one out?

```
function nmbr0(){
var displaySpan = document.getElementById('result0');
displaySpan.innerHTML = 0;
}
function nmbr1(){
var displaySpan = document.getElementById('result1');
displaySpan.innerHTML = 1;
}
function nmbr2(){
var displaySpan = document.getElementById('result2');
displaySpan.innerHTML = 2;
}

 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr0()"> 0 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr1()"> 1 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr2()"> 2 </button>

You have entered
<span id="result0"></span>
<span id="result1"></span>
<span id="result2"></span>
```

This is my output after clicking on 4321:

[image]

Comment: Store your results in an array and then iterate over the array when you're ready to show what was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the spans are already defined in ascending order, so even if you print 2 before 1, it'll still go inside the 'result2' span.

```
<span id="result0"></span>
<span id="result1"></span>
<span id="result2"></span>
```

How about this alternate instead?

```
<button type="button" onClick="print(this)"> 0 </button>
<button type="button" onClick="print(this)"> 1 </button>
<button type="button" onClick="print(this)"> 2 </button>

You have entered
<span id="displaySpan"></span>

<script>
    var displaySpan = document.getElementById('displaySpan')
    function print(button){
        displaySpan.innerHTML += button.innerHTML
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to create a function for each button number because you can use selector for that. Look a simple solution for that:

```js
var element = "";
$("button").click(function() {
  element += $(this).html(); //Get the button number
  $("#result").html(element);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>0</button>
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
<button>6</button>
<button>7</button>
<button>8</button>
<button>9</button>


<div>
  <strong>You have entered:</strong> <span id="result"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think they wanted buttons numbered zero through nine.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was behaving unexpectedly becase you were using `ids` for each button text display, so the order was already predefined in them from 0-10.

You can append the numbers to the html itself like below

```js
function nmbr(num){
var displaySpan = document.getElementById('numbers');
//appending one after another
displaySpan.innerHTML += num + ' ';
}
```

```html
You have entered<br>
<span id="numbers"></span>
<br>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr('0')"> 0 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr('1')"> 1 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr('2')"> 2 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr('3')"> 3 </button>
 <button type="button" onClick="nmbr('4')"> 4 </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function showButtonClicked ()
{
  // Get the output node
  let output = document.querySelector( '.output' );

  // Get the buttons parent and add a click event on it
  document.querySelector( '.buttons' ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    
    // Get the clicked element
    let target = event.target;
    
    // If it is not a button, return
    if ( target.nodeName !== 'BUTTON' ) return;
    
    // Add the button number to the output
    output.textContent += ` ${ target.textContent }`;
  
  });
}

showButtonClicked();
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>0</button>
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>7</button>
  <button>8</button>
  <button>9</button>
</div>

<p>You have entered : </p>
<div class="output"></div>
```